# Where did my file /etc/ppp/ip-up go after upgrading to Lion?

Tags: macos, upgrade, vpn

I upgraded to OS X 10.7 this morning and upon attempting to connect to my corporate VPN, I discovered that my script at `/etc/ppp/ip-up` has disappeared. Has anyone else encountered this problem, or do you know where it might have ended up?

Comment: If you grab a copy from your backup, does it still work for you?

Comment: I'm ashamed to say that I made major changes to the file since my last backup and didn't back up prior to the upgrade.

Comment: Oh no! Yikes - at lest you know a little about changing it. I feel a little bad for asking - hope it gets sorted out for you or someone here has a copy they can share. I would try entering anything in VPN software and see if it still creates a new script that you can start with.

Comment: Still happening in Yosemite - upgrading from 10.10.0 to 10.10.1 nuked mine (again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It very likely got overwritten. The upgrade does nothing to back up what it considers "system files" and simply overwrites them with the latest version.

Another good reason to do a full backup before upgrading.